# Djangoでidをuuidにするとmigrationがバグる

Tags: python, python3, django

Djangoで、

```
import uuid

class Hoge(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4().hex,
        editable=False,
        max_length=32,
    )
    # 略
```

として、
`python manage.py makemigrations`
をすると、`- Alter field id on hoge`
と表示され、adminでも反映されているのを確認できるが、
もう一度`python manage.py makemigrations`とすると、何も変更を加えていないのに
`- Alter field id on hoge`と再度表示される。
また、`python manage.py makemigrations`をするたびに
`- Alter field id on hoge`が表示される。

Comment: 内容が毎回変わる, という意味であれば, `uuid4()` はランダムなので毎回変わります
(別の意味であれば, わからない)

Comment: 何も変更を加えていないのに、migrationすると毎回 -Alter field id on hoge と出てしまうのがおかしいと思ったのですが。

Comment: @oriri ありがとうございます。解決しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UUIDFieldにしたら直りました。

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

`uuid.uuid4().hex`とするのが悪かったようです。
毎回関数が実行されるから。